# switching between views

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make my app view multiple views 
I made 2 xml files (main, sub) 
and I switch between them using :

setContentView(R.Layout.main);

setContentView(R.Layout.sub);

When I switch to the sub, it switches fine. However, When I switch back to main, the app crashes and I have no clue why it did that.

The only line that seems to make it crash is the calling of setContentView(R.Layout.main); for the second time.
any clue on that ?

Comment: mmm i dont think so, calling multiple times to setContentView with differents layout cannot be the only reason, can you put some entrys from the logcat?

Answer (score 4):

You should provide the logcat output so that we can know what the problem is. However, I'd recommend to use something like [`ViewFlipper`](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example/) instead of switching views using `setContentView`.

Comment: I too, would suggest using a ViewFlipper.  They are very easy to use and you can also easily apply nice animations to them!

Comment: LogCat is a good place to start,as it tells you where the code crashed.

Comment: sherif also try using ViewSwitcher http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html